# Proof of discontinuity at a point

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ if $x = 0$ is continuous everywhere except $x = 0$. Here is my attempt.

> We first prove continuity. Let $x_0 > 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Set $\delta = \min\left(\frac{x_0}{2}, \frac{\epsilon x_0^2}{2}\right)$. Then $|x - x_0| < \delta$ implies
> \begin{align*}
> |f(x) - f(x_0)| & = \left \lvert \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x_0} \right \rvert \\
> & = \frac{|x-x_0|}{xx_0} \\
> & < \frac{\frac{x_0^2}{2} \epsilon}{\frac{x_0}{2}} \\
> & = \epsilon. 
> \end{align*}

I'm stuck on the $x < 0$ case. In the above work, the step $|xx_0| = xx_0$ breaks down in that case unless $x < 0$, but $\delta$ can't depend on $x$.

To prove discontinuity at $x = 0$, I need to find $\epsilon > 0$. so that $\forall \delta > 0$, there exists $y$ such that $|y| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(y)| \geq \epsilon$. Here is my attempt.

> Let $\epsilon = 0$, $\delta > 0$, and pick $0 > y > \delta$. Then $|y| = -y < \delta$. Also:
> $$f(x) - f(y)| = \left \lvert f(0) - \frac{1}{y} \right \rvert = \frac{1}{y} < \delta.$$

This fails because $\delta$ has to be arbitrary, unless I can begin with the case where $\delta < 1$ and then take the case where $\delta \geq 1$.

Comment: What point are you trying to prove it is continuous at?  At $x_0$ or at $x$? And which is the value you are picking withing $\delta$?  $x$ or $x_0$.  If you are proving it at $x=x_s$ then pick $\delta < |x_s|$ and therefore when you pick $x_t$ so that $|x_t - x_s| < \delta$ you will be assured $x_s$ and $x_t$ are both the same sign.

Answer (score 1):

Your 3rd display line's denominator should be $x_0^2/2,$ not $x_0/2.$ (Typo?) This step should be justified by stating that if $x_0>0$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $x>x_0-\delta\ge x_0-x_0/2=x_0/2>0,$ so $(x_0x)^{-1}\le (x_0\cdot x_0/2)^{-1}.$

You can do the cases $x_0>0$ and $x_0<0$ at once. Let $\delta=\min (|x_0|/2,\epsilon x_0^2/2).$  Now if $x_0\ne 0$ and $|x-x_0|<|x_0|/2$ then $|x|>|x_0|/2>0$. Hence for any $x_0\ne 0$  we assert that $$|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |x-x_0|<|x_0|/2 \implies |x_0x|=|x_0|\cdot |x|> |x_0|\cdot |x_0|/2=x_0^2/2>0.$$

So if $x_0\ne 0$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then  $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x_0-x|/|x_0x|\le|x_0-x|/ (x_0^2/2)<(\epsilon x_0^2/2)/(x_0^2/2)=\epsilon.$$

Comment: The idea to tame the wild denominator $|x_0x|$ is to find a constraint (...depending only on $x_0$...) on $|x|$ that keeps it away from $0$, i.e. $|x-x_0|<|x_0|/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$x_n=\frac 1n \text{ and }\; y_n=-\frac 1n$$

We have

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to+\infty}y_n=\color{red}{0}$$

$$f(x_n)=n\;\text{ and }\; f(y_n)=-n$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(x_n)\ne\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(y_n)$$

thus, by the sequential catacterisation of the limit, we conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to\color{red}{0}}f(x)\;\text{ doesn't exist}$$

Answer (score 0):

$x_0<0$ sets up the same way.

Suppose $x_0<0$
Let $\delta = \min (\frac {|x_0|}{2},\frac {|x_0|^2}{2})$

$|\frac {1}{x} - \frac {1}{x_0}| = |\frac {x_0-x}{xx_0}| < \epsilon $

$|x-x_0|<\delta \implies x_0<x<0 \implies xx_0 > 0$

$|\frac {1}{x} - \frac {1}{x_0}|< \frac {\delta}{xx_0} \le \epsilon$

In the next step, we must show that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $\delta$ there is an $x$ with $|x-0|<\delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(0)| > \epsilon$

Note we can not choose $\epsilon = 0$ as in the work above.  But we can choose $\epsilon  = 1$

Then with $x = \min (\frac 12, \frac {\delta}{2}), |f(x) - f(0)|>\epsilon$

Comment: Can you explain where the assumption that $\delta \leq \frac{|x_0|}{2}$ is worked in? I'm having trouble understanding the conclusion $x_0 < x < 0$. We end up with $x_0 - \delta < x < x_0 + \delta$, but I don't know how to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

To prove it is continuous at $x_0\ne 0$ let $\delta < |x_0|$.

Then if $|x-x_0| < \delta$ then

either $x_0 - \delta < x<  x_0 +\delta < 0$ if $x_0 < 0$. or $0 < x_0-\delta < x < x_0 + \delta$ if $x_0> 0$.

Either way you have $x,x_0$ are the same sign.  And $xx_0 > 0$.